# Reuse dynamic parameter type in other parameter (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm currently working on a TypeScript project and am trying to properly define a function to attach an event handler to multiple events.

Now, what I've settled on (and I'm not as much looking for advice as to whether this is a great idea, but more on how to do it well) is a simple function that I can pass the event types, the receiver of the event and the callback.

Something along these lines:

```js
const addListeners = (events, htmlElement, handler) = { ... };

addListeners(['click', 'touchstart'], btn, eventType => {
  console.log(`Handling ${eventType} event`);
});
```

Now, to the handler I want to pass the event type back in, just so it can follow slightly different paths based on which event it is acting on.

The problem is, how do I tell TypeScript, the only allowed values for that parameter are whatever I passed in as the first argument to the `addListeners` function?

This is what I have so far:

```
const addListeners = <E extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap, Events extends Array<E>>(events: Events, htmlElement: HTMLElement, handler: (event: string) => void): void => {
  events.forEach(e => {
    htmlElement.addEventListener(e, () => {
      handler(e, htmlElement);
    });
  });
};
```

It's the `(event: string) => void` (the last argument) that I'd like to narrow down. I have a feeling it should be possible, but I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want it to be `"click" | "touchstart"`. In other words, a union of the elements of the array. You can do that by indexing into the array with `number`:

```
const addListeners = <E extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap, Events extends Array<E>>(events: Events, htmlElement: HTMLElement, handler: (event: Events[number]) => void): void => {
```

But wait. You already have the elements! It's `E`:

```
const addListeners = <E extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap, Events extends Array<E>>(events: Events, htmlElement: HTMLElement, handler: (event: E) => void): void => {
```